# Invalid object name error while creating function

Tags: sql-server, functions, errors

I have this function `get_department`. Inside the function there is a function call for `get_po_amount`.

The `get_po_amount` function doesn't exist anymore, so when I try to create the Main function `get_Department`, I get the error "invalid object name get_po_amount".

Is there any way that I could create the function by not creating the function inside.

I have the same issue with views also. Calling a view inside another view.

I created these functions just to show an example, I need to do this on a large database.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_DEPARTEMNET]
(
    @DEPTNO NVARCHAR(100)
    
)
    RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
RETURN 
   (    
        SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[dept] WHERE DEPTNO=(SELECT [dbo].[GET_PO_AMOUNT](@DEPTNO)))
GO
```

Comment: This seems really confusing.  If you are passing in the department number, why not just use that in the first query, SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[dept] WHERE DEPTNO=@DEPTNO, instead of passing it into the subquery, which is either really poorly named or not returning the right thing

Comment: That's y said I gave the function just as an example.

Comment: Do you see why using fake code that is confusing might make it hard for people to answer your question?

Comment: Its confusing because you didn't read what I wrote. You should have read it first completely  .There are other people who read it right and answered . They didn't see anything confusing .

Answer (score 5):

These things are strongly typed, in the sense that when you create a function or view, SQL Server needs to know what it returns. Having it use some non-existent object prohibits this strong typing, so that isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to find the hierarchy order of views and function to create like that .